# custom post and taxonomy custom url?

Tags: wordpress, url

Below is the code that creates the custom post with taxonomy.

```
add_action('init', 'product_post_type');

function product_post_type() {
    register_taxonomy('products', 'products', array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'label'         => 'Product category',
        'query_var'     => true,
        'rewrite'       => array(
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    ));

    register_post_type('product', array(
        'labels'            => array(
            'name'              => __('Products'),
            'singular_name'     => 'product' ,
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add new Product',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Product'
        ),
        'taxonomies'        => array('products'),
        'supports'          => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'public'            => true,
        'has_archive'       => false,
        'capability_type'   =>'post'
    ));

    add_post_type_support('product', array('comments'));
}
```

Below is the url that shows the post in a taxonomy https://localhst.com/wordpress/product/project/ but I want to show the custom taxonomy the post belongs to in url so for example the project custom post has target category assigned so I want the url for project post is https://localhst.com/wordpress/products/target/project/ but it is currently https://localhst.com/wordpress/product/project/

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: please describe your problem better, misunderstand you. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I just want to change the custom post url for example for project custom post I want the url   https://localhst.com/wordpress/products/target/project/  so here in this url products is the custom post type, target is the product  category taxonomy and project is the post of products custom post type. The current url of project custom post is https://localhst.com/wordpress/product/project/ but I want https://localhst.com/wordpress/products/target/project/ so url should include custom post products, 'target' products taxonomy and project post name in url.